# Valgrind Memory leak and invalid free error

Tags: c, linux, shell, valgrind

I am trying to **parse an input** for my simple shell program to **execute**, though it is working as expected but i am having a **valgrind memory leak and invalid free() error **. I have tried to figure out the issue but to no avail, Thanks in advance

```
#cisfun$ /bin/ls -l
token: /bin/ls
arg_list[0]: /bin/ls
token: -l
arg_list[1]: -l
token: (null)
cmd: /bin/ls
total 204
-rwxrw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    104 Jul  2 12:39 AUTHORS
-rwxrw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant     23 Jun 14 16:25 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    575 Jul  4 08:25 execute.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    197 Aug 13 09:17 free_arg.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 142144 Jul  3 05:04 hbtn_ls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    810 Aug 13 09:15 parse_arg.c
-rwxrw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    789 Jul  4 12:05 puts.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  27888 Aug 13 09:15 shell
-rwxrw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   1186 Aug 13 10:47 shell.c
-rwxrw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    398 Jul  4 10:29 shell.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    156 Jul  4 08:31 sig_handler.c
#cisfun$ ^Z
==8999== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==8999==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8999==    by 0x109423: free_arg (free_arg.c:12)
==8999==    by 0x10991C: main (shell.c:77)
==8999==  Address 0x4a4f040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 120 free'd
==8999==    at 0x483CA3F: free (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8999==    by 0x10990D: main (shell.c:76)
==8999==  Block was alloc'd at
==8999==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8999==    by 0x48DD573: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==8999==    by 0x1097EB: main (shell.c:47)
==8999==
==8999==
==8999== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8999==     in use at exit: 11 bytes in 2 blocks
==8999==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 2,227 bytes allocated
==8999==
==8999== 11 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8999==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8999==    by 0x109528: parse_arg (parse_arg.c:29)
==8999==    by 0x109843: main (shell.c:54)
==8999==
==8999== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8999==    definitely lost: 11 bytes in 2 blocks
==8999==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8999==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8999==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8999==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8999==
==8999== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8999== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is my main function

```
47         nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin);
48         if (nread == -1)
49             break;
50
51         if (line[nread - 1] == '\n')
52             line[nread - 1] = '\0';
53
54         arg_list = parse_arg(line);
55
56         cmd = arg_list[0];
57         printf("cmd: %s\n", cmd);
58         if (cmd == NULL || *cmd == '\0')
59             continue;
60
61
62
63         if (stat(cmd, &st) == 0)
64         {
65             execute(arg_list, prog_name);
66         }
67         else
68         {
69             perror(prog_name);
70         }
71     }
72
73     if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
74         _puts("\n");
75
76     free(line);
77     free_arg(arg_list);
78     return (0);
```

and the Parse_arg() and free_arg() function;

```
 7 char **parse_arg(char *arg)
  8 {
  9     char **arg_list;
 10     char *str, *token;
 11     int i, j = 1;
 12
 13     arg_list = malloc(sizeof(*arg_list) * j);
 14     if (arg_list == NULL)
 15         return (NULL);
 16
 17     for (i = 0, str = arg; ;str = NULL, i++)
 18     {
 19         token = strtok(str, " ");
 20         printf("token: %s\n", token);
 21
 22         if (token == NULL)
 23         {
 24             arg_list[i] = NULL;
 25             break;
 26         }
 27         else
 28         {
 29             arg_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1);
 30             if (arg_list[i] == NULL)
 31             {
 32                 while (i--)
 33                     free(arg_list[i]);
 34
 35                 free(arg_list);
 36                 return (NULL);
 37             }
 38             arg_list[i] = token;
 39             printf("arg_list[%d]: %s\n", i, arg_list[i]);
 40         }
 41         arg_list = realloc(arg_list, sizeof(*arg_list) * ++j);
 42         if (arg_list == NULL)
 43              return (NULL);
 44
 45     }
 46     return (arg_list);
 47 }
```

```
 6 void free_arg(char **arg)
  7 {
  8     int i;
  9
 10     for (i = 0; arg[i] != NULL; i++)
 11     {
 12         free(arg[i]);
 13     }
 14     free(arg);
 15 }
```

Comment: Bro, [sscce.org](http://sscce.org)... To me there is no memory leak or invalid free... How are we supposed to reproduce the problem if you give us code that doesn't even compile? Read sscce.org in full before you fix this question.

Answer (score 1):

`arg_list` contains a pointer to `line`. So `line` is being freed twice. Once in main (76) and once in free_arg. Remove the line `free(line)` in your main function.

Comment: I have removed it but i am still having the same issue

Comment: did you store `line` in multiple times in `arg_list`?

Comment: i broke the line(string) into parts using strtok(), then i stored it in arg_list

Comment: @Bayeroabdul for all we know you may be executing a stale binary because as far as we can see ... your code ... doesn't compile!

Answer (score 0):

```
29  arg_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token) + 1);
30  if (arg_list[i] == NULL)
31  {
32      while (i--)
33          free(arg_list[i]);
34
35      free(arg_list);
36      return (NULL);
37  }

    // arg_list[i]` points at an allocated buffer.

38  arg_list[i] = token;

    // But, ignore that buffer and reassign it to a local variable
    // The allocated buffer is now orphaned
```

You probably want `strcpy( arg_list[i], token );